# Выведение таблицы в скрипте

Tags: javascript

```
function OnSelectionChange(select) {
let selname = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

switch (selname.value) {
    case 'Выберите модель автомобиля':
        document.getElementById("wTable").innerText = "";
        break;

    case 'ГАЗель до 2002 года':
        document.getElementById("wTable").innerHTML = "222";
        break;


}
```

};

Имеется скрипт, который получает значение строки из выпадающего списка и выдает в ответе строку в . Интересует, каким образом можно в ответе выдавать таблицу из двух столбцов с различным количеством строк в ней?

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "ответом" - *выдает в ответе строку* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строку вы должны собрать сами в цикле и вставить ее в innerHTML.
Например

```
let str = ""; 

for(let i=0; i< 4;i++) 
    str += '<tr>' +'<td>'+1+'</td><td>'+2+'</td>'+ '</tr>';

document.getElementById("wTable").innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Так не будет же работать. Вы же используете свойство `innerText`!

Comment: Да поправил на innerHTML не обратил внимания при копировании, что ТС использует разные методы для первого и второго case.